# More effective way to write following SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I am writing a query to return a list of articles for the news portal homepage.
Requirement is following.

Each category which needs to be on the homepage needs to display 5 articles by following criteria.

Each category needs to have one article which is main news for the category, followed by 4 most popular news at the time being.
If there is no first news for category set, then display 5 most popular insted.

I wrote a SQL Function which has CategoryID parameter and another SQL procedure which calls that function N Times.

Is there more efficient way to write this query?

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_FetchHomepageCategory] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @categoryId int

)
RETURNS @ArticlesToReturn TABLE 
                      ( Id int, 
                        Title nvarchar(500),
                        Slug nvarchar(500),
                        Summary nvarchar(1500),
                        IsCategoryFirst bit,
                        RootCategoryId int,
                        RootCategory nvarchar(500),
                        OldFacebookCommentsUrl nvarchar(500),
                        Icon nvarchar(500),
                        TopicName nvarchar(500),
                        MainArticlePhoto nvarchar(500),
                        FrontPagePhoto nvarchar(500),
                        PublishDate datetime

                      )  
AS
BEGIN


    -- select category first news if any
    INSERT INTO @ArticlesToReturn
    SELECT TOP 1
    ART.Id, ART.Title, ART.InitialTitle, ART.Summary,ART.IsCategoryFirst,
    ART.RootCategoryId, CAT.Name, ART.OldFacebookCommentsUrl, ICO.CssClass,
    ART.TopicName, ART.MainArticlePhoto, ART.FrontPagePhoto, ART.PublishDate
    FROM Articles ART WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN ArticleViewCountSum AVS WITH (NOLOCK) ON AVS.ArticleId = ART.Id 
    INNER JOIN Categories CAT WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAT.Id = ART.RootCategoryId 
    LEFT JOIN ArticleIcons ICO WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICO.Id = ART.IconId
    WHERE ART.RootCategoryId = @categoryId
    AND ART.PublishDate < GETDATE() 
    AND ART.Active = 1
    AND IsCategoryFirst = 1

    -- select 5 most popular by coefficient
    INSERT INTO @ArticlesToReturn
    SELECT TOP 5 
    ART.Id, ART.Title, ART.InitialTitle, ART.Summary,ART.IsCategoryFirst,
    ART.RootCategoryId, CAT.Name, ART.OldFacebookCommentsUrl, ICO.CssClass,
    ART.TopicName, ART.MainArticlePhoto, ART.FrontPagePhoto, ART.PublishDate
    FROM Articles ART WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN ArticleViewCountSum AVS WITH (NOLOCK) ON AVS.ArticleId = ART.Id 
    INNER JOIN Categories CAT WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAT.Id = ART.RootCategoryId 
    LEFT JOIN ArticleIcons ICO WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICO.Id = ART.IconId
    WHERE ART.RootCategoryId = @categoryId
    AND ART.PublishDate < GETDATE() 
    AND ART.Active = 1

    ORDER BY  ART.Coefficient  DESC


    RETURN 

END
```

**Stored procedure**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fetch_HomePageArticles]

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @dateNow datetime = GETDATE();

    -- first main news
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Articles 
    WHERE IsFirst = 1 AND PublishDate < @dateNow


    --TODO: featured
    SELECT TOP 10 * From Featured 
    WHERE PublishDate < @dateNow AND Active = 1 
    ORDER BY PublishDate DESC


    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(3) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(150) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(1523) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(1509) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(1569) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(1545) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(1548) 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Fn_FetchHomepageCategory(67)

END
```

I tried to modify function to have only one SELECT and included `Order BY IsFirstCategory DESC`, but query ran much slower then.

Answer (score 0):

One potential improvement would be merging two SELECT clauses in the Fn_FetchHomepageCategory function into one single query by adding a new made-up Coefficient parameter:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 5 ART.Id, 
    ART.Title, 
    ART.InitialTitle, 
    ART.Summary, 
    ART.IsCategoryFirst, 
    ART.RootCategoryId, 
    CAT.Name, 
    ART.OldFacebookCommentsUrl, 
    ICO.CssClass, 
    ART.TopicName, 
    ART.MainArticlePhoto, 
    ART.FrontPagePhoto, 
    ART.PublishDate
 FROM 
  Articles ART WITH (NOLOCK) 
  INNER JOIN ArticleViewCountSum AVS WITH (NOLOCK) ON AVS.ArticleId = ART.Id 
  INNER JOIN Categories CAT WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAT.Id = ART.RootCategoryId 
  LEFT JOIN ArticleIcons ICO WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICO.Id = ART.IconId 
WHERE 
  ART.RootCategoryId = @categoryId 
  AND ART.PublishDate < GETDATE() 
  AND ART.Active = 1 
ORDER BY 
  CASE IsCategoryFirst
  WHEN 1    THEN 1000000
  ELSE  ART.Coefficient 
  END DESC
```

You can replace 1000000 with another big number. Its only point is assigning the highest co-efficiency score possible to the post that have IsCategoryFirst = 1.
Please note that it works fine only if you have only one post with IsCategoryFirst = 1.

Comment: this is neat change in code, but it slowed down my query by 3 times.